# Why don't we add the option "other sites" in the close votes option?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, migration

We all know that some questions are posted in PSE but they should belong to another Stack Exchange site.

When you vote to close a question, via
Close question > A community specific reason > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

then the two only options are physics meta and mathematics.

I've read in other posts that only sites whose migrations have been remarkably usual have been included, and those are physics meta and mathematics.

The question is: **Why don't we include the option *other site*?**

I'm asking this because there are many times in which I find questions belonging to several sites: biology, hsm, chemistry, geology, and so on. The problem, of course, is that this list is too diverse to ask for a mathematics-like status of all those other sites.

Therefore the question is just: why isn't there an option simply called "other site"?

In my opinion, that option should display a selection menu with the list of all sites, and I don't think that's so hard to do, but I'd understand that it can be complex to run afterwards. However, I find the option "Other" quite neccesary. Such an option would just call for moderator intervention, a moderator who would decide where to migrate it.

Would that "other" option be possible? Thank you

Comment: Related: [Why is question-migration limited?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6801/106502), [Can the flag for migration be generalized?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4869/106502)

Answer (score 1):

When you vote to close a question as "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network," the question is automatically migrated to the other site. By design, this is limited to a few sites for every site on the Stack Exchange network. If a question should be migrated to another site, just suggest it with a custom flag. Migrations are rare enough that any changes to this probably aren't worth the developer time.

A drop down menu probably isn't a good idea anyway. You shouldn't be suggesting migration to a site unless you are familiar with that site's policies. Otherwise it is quite likely the migration will be rejected.

An "Other" option isn't likely to be very helpful. If a question is off-topic and you don't know where to migrate it, just vote to close it.

Comment: If you really *really want* an option where you can type any site's name into the "belongs on another site" close reason, you can enable this feature by winning an election for community moderator. (Smiley face emoji)

Answer (score 1):

The option already exists:

1. Vote to close the question as off-topic, with a custom reason if necessary, explaining why the question is *not* a good fit for this site.
2. Raise a moderator flag indicating that migration to site X would be appropriate.

Point 1 is particularly necessary: it is not enough for the question to be on-topic elsewhere, it also needs to be off-topic here. In other words, if migration is appropriate, then the question should be closed as off-topic anyways.

Comment: how do you “Vote to close the question as off-topic”? I looked through the options and didn’t see one labeled similar to that.

Comment: @Dale Close > A community-specific reason > Other, and then add a comment into the text box explaining why the question is off-topic for the site.

Comment: got it, thanks!